# function classes function is not returning to controller classes calling function

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model, modelmapper

i am calling a function from controller class. function is defined in another class function. but before executing return code it gives error. (as debugging) it jumps from the line **modelMap.put("list", arraylist);** it gives exception, nullpointerexception.

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm")
    public String getData() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        function obj = new function();
        ModelMap modelMap = null;
        obj.getdata(modelMap);
        return "index";
    }
```

**function.java**

```
public ModelMap getdata(ModelMap modelMap) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SqlRowSet srs = null;
        ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource = new connection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
        JdbcTemplate get = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        //Operation
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
        srs = get.queryForRowSet(sql);
        while (srs.next()) {
            pojo obj = new pojo();
            obj.setEmail_id(srs.getString("email_id"));
            obj.setPassword(srs.getString("pwd"));
            arraylist.add(obj);
        }

        modelMap.put("list", arraylist);
        return modelMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`modelMap` is `null`, that's why you get `NullPointerException`. You need to initialize it

```
ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
obj.getdata(modelMap);
```

Comment: thankss.. its returning .. :) but new problem ,, after returning to controller obj is null. although modelMap has data.

Comment: @SurajRoy There is nothing in the code you posted that will make `obj` `null`. Further more, if `obj` was `null` you couldn't `obj.getdata(modelMap);` (I assume you mean `obj` from `function obj = new function();`).